# Effectiveness in keeping value type as member of reference type

Tags: c#, .net

In my application i created some class.
In some scenario i need to know the class size ( bytes count ).
So i think of a way to do it and i know that i can call binaryformatter serialize and see what is the serialize result ( byte[] ) and take the length of this result.

But the binaryformatter serialize takes 2 milliseconds this look like bad practice for me.

My other way is to hold shadow struct and use Marshal.sizeof(...)
This take 0.6754 Milliseconds

**But i'm not sure my Effectiveness in hold struct in a class.**

The code:

```
public class DommyElement
{
    public int Val1 { get; set; }
    public int Val2 { get; set; }
    public int Val3 { get; set; }
    public int Val4 { get; set; }

    public int ElementSize()
    {
        return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(ShadowElement));
    }

    private struct ShadowElement
    {
        int Val1;
        int Val2;
        int Val3;
        int Val4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just return the size of of 4 int?

Comment: because on some classes the fields are much more complex .. and i want to do it dynamically without using hard code

Comment: But you are having performance issues.

Comment: no i don't have. just want to know if someone see something i'm not